# Am I logged into Google+? (Server Side)

Tags: asp.net, callback, google-plus

How can I tell if I'm logged into Google+ or not?  I want to determine this with server-side code (ASP.Net if possible).  Every page Google serves can tell you this, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

I am able to do this client side, but the Ajax and callbacks and passing data back and forth is really clunky.  Somehow, the code below uses a callback (signinCallback) in which a magical authorization result appears that gets passed to the callback.  I just want to be able to get this value server-side.  Any ideas?

```
<asp:Label ID="GSignIn" runat="server"
                    class="g-signin"
                    data-callback="signinCallback"
                    data-clientid="{myclientID}"
                    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
                    data-scope="profile">
                  </asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Client side code knows if the user it authenticated with Google because Google iframes are loaded and they tell your JS. The only way for your server to know is by passing the results of that interaction via AJAX from the client.